# Images are only filled after filtering

Tags: c#, .net, sitefinity

I am developing a website with custom content types. I created the content types with the module builder (latest Sitefinity).

All custom content types contain images. I can see the images in the backend, after creating the items. When I am querying the items with

```
var dynamicModuleManager = DynamicModuleManager.GetManager(PROVIDER_NAME);
var editionType = TypeResolutionService.ResolveType(TYPE_NAME);
IQueryable<DynamicContent> allEditions = dynamicModuleManager.GetDataItems(editionType);
```

And getting the images with:

```
allEditions.First().DynamicContent.GetValue("Images");
```

the return value is an empty list. I also tried to cast them to ContentLink[] as mentioned [here](http://www.sitefinity.com/blogs/team-blog/2012/01/19/retrieving_data_from_dynamic_modules_using_the_module_builder_api) and [here](http://www.sitefinity.com/developer-network/forums/module-builder/getting-image-field) but this throws an exception. What works is a cast to ICollection or calling the GetRelatedItems("Images") method but the enumerables are empty.

In one of the content types there is an field of type Address. After filtering these items with:

```
((IGeoLocationManager)dynamicModuleManager).FilterByGeoLocation
```

the Images field is not empty anymore.

In other content types I do not have this option. Can someone help me?

Best regards,
David

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Though not a real answer to my question, using

```
DynamicContent editionItem = dynamicModuleManager.GetDataItem(editionType, id);
```

The images are filled, so that I can iterate over all items in `allEditions` and get each item again with a call to `dynamicModuleManager.GetDataItem(editionType, id)`